# can't change user.name in Teamcity on server2008

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to have the build agent run under another account than the build-in SYSTEM account. On our previous windows 2003 box this is no issue; just adding it to the buildAgent.properties and configuring the buildservice to run under the required account works fine.

However, on our server 2008 instalation the new setting is not picked up. Can anyone confirm changing this setting actually works on a server2008? / What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer on the Teamcity forum [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-5527), apparantly it's a known issue and will be fixed in 7.1, but for now there are the following options:

- install 7.1 EAP
- run the agent using the console
- apply a dirty, dirty hack in the registry

Upgrading from 7 to 7.1 resulted into a non-working TC installation so I opted for option 2:

To run the agent.bat we put a batch file in the Buildagent directory containing:
%windir%\system32\runas.exe /savecred /user:domain\user  "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k D:\Teamcity\buildagent3\bin\agent.bat start"